# unsupported operation _FusedBatchNormV3 with tensorRT and jetson tx2

Tags: python, batch-normalization, tensorrt, nvidia-jetson

On a Jetson TX2 I am running:

- Linux4Tegra R32.2.1
- UFF Version 0.6.3
- TensorRT 5.1.6.1
- Cuda 10
- Python 3.6.8

I get this error message:

```
[TensorRT] ERROR: UffParser: Validator error: sequential/batch_normalization_1/FusedBatchNormV3: Unsupported operation _FusedBatchNormV3
```

From this code:

```
output_nodes = [args.output_node_names]
input_node = args.input_node_name
frozen_graph_pb = args.frozen_graph_pb

uff_model = uff.from_tensorflow(frozen_graph_pb, output_nodes) . #Successfully creates uff model

network = builder.create_network()
G_LOGGER = trt.Logger(trt.Logger.INFO)
builder = trt.Builder(G_LOGGER)
builder.max_batch_size = 10
builder.max_workspace_size = 1 << 30

data_type = trt.DataType.FLOAT

parser = trt.UffParser()
input_verified =parser.register_input(input_node, (1,234,234,3))       #returns true
output_verified = parser.register_output(output_nodes[0])              #returns true
buffer_verified = parser.parse_buffer(uff_model, network, data_type)   #returns false
```

The uff model was created successfully.

The parser successfully registered the inputs and outputs.

Parsing the buffer fails with the error above.

Does anyone know if FusedBatchNormV3 is truly not supported in tensorRT and if not is there an existing plugin that I can pull using the graph surgeon module?